# How to draw a multi level pie chart using html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a `pie-chart` shape on a `canvas` element, however I can't find any function that does this by itself.
Is there an easy way to do a `pie chart like below image`

[image: This pie indicates the progress of each slice]?

Comment: You can easily draw wedges with varying radii with: `context.beginPath(); context.moveTo(centerX, centerY); context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startRadianAngle, endRadianAngle); context.closePath(); context.fillStyle='yourChosenColor'; context.fill(); context.strokeStyle='white'; context.stroke()`

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.I tried what you have suggested .Can you please tell me how to draw another arc  to show progress of the arc which is like above pie?

Comment: I've posted a quick example for you to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starting example for you that draws arcs using a recallable function:

Remember that the starting & ending arc angles are `Radians`. You can convert degrees to radians like this: `radians = degrees * Math.PI/180`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.font = '14px verdana';

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var myColor = ["Green", "Red", "Blue"];
var myData = [30, 15, 38, 22, 30, 20, 10];
var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 100;

ctx.globalAlpha=0.50;
pieChart(myData, myColor);
ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;

function pieChart(data, colors){
  // calc data total
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    total += data[i];
  }
  // calc sweep angles for each piece of pie
  var sweeps = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sweeps.push(data[i] / total * PI2);
  }
  // draw outer pie
  var accumAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sweeps.length; i++) {
    var f=randomColor();
    drawWedge(radius, accumAngle, accumAngle + sweeps[i], f, data[i]);
    accumAngle += sweeps[i];
  }
  // draw inner percent-complete wedges
  var accumAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sweeps.length; i++) {
    var r=radius*(Math.random()*70+20)/100;
    var f=randomColor();
    drawWedge(r,accumAngle, accumAngle + sweeps[i], f, data[i]);
    accumAngle += sweeps[i];
  }  
}

function drawWedge(radius, startAngle, endAngle, fill, label) {
  // draw the wedge
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = fill;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function randomColor(){ 
    return('#'+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000) + 0x1000000).toString(16).substr(1));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi Mark,Can you help me adding a label on hover of each arc

Comment: Hey, family has me short of time so you might post another question about the hover labels :-)